# why just the first element in <ul> could responded to query function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web.py

guys.I am now using web.py +jQuery to finish a small website.However I encountered a problem.The example code as blow.When I created a group of li elements,the jQuery event only responded to the first element.But others never call the jQuery function.Why it happened?Many thinks:)

**html&python**

```
<ul id="products" style="list-style:none;">
    $for item in data.response["Galleries"]:
     <li style="float:left" id="photoLink">
      <a href="$item['PhotoUrl']">
        <img src=$item["PhotoUrl"] alt="加载失败" style="max-width:75px;max-height:75px" title="点击查看大图"/>
         </a>
        <div id="img_menu" style="height:20px;width:75px;background-color:black;opacity:0.5"/>
     </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$$(document).ready(function(){
  $$("#photoLink").mouseenter(function(){
    $$("#img_menu").css("margin-top","-20px");
  });

  $$("#photoLink").mouseleave(function(){
    $$("#img_menu").css("margin-top","0px");
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML **IDs must be unique**, use class instead like

```
<ul id="products" style="list-style:none;">
    $for item in data.response["Galleries"]:
     <li style="float:left" class="photoLink">
      <a href="$item['PhotoUrl']">
        <img src=$item["PhotoUrl"] alt="加载失败" style="max-width:75px;max-height:75px" title="点击查看大图"/>
         </a>
        <div class="img_menu" style="height:20px;width:75px;background-color:black;opacity:0.5"/>
     </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$$(document).ready(function(){
  $$(".photoLink").mouseenter(function(){
    $$(this).find(".img_menu").css("margin-top","-20px");
  });

  $$(".photoLink").mouseleave(function(){
    $$(this).find(".img_menu").css("margin-top","0px");
  });
});
</script>
```

Additionally You can use [**.hover()**](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$$(document).ready(function(){
  $$(".photoLink").hover(function(){
    $$(this).find(".img_menu").css("margin-top","-20px");
  }, function(){
    $$(this).find(".img_menu").css("margin-top","0px");
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Id` can't no be duplicate on the page. They must be unique. If there are same multiple Ids presents on the page, selector selects only the first one. So you need to use *class* selector instead of *Id*.

```
<li style="float:left" class ="photoLink">
      <a href="$item['PhotoUrl']">
        <img src=$item["PhotoUrl"] alt="加载失败" style="max-width:75px;max-height:75px" title="点击查看大图"/>
         </a>
        <div class="img_menu" style="height:20px;width:75px;background-color:black;opacity:0.5"/>
</li>
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$$(document).ready(function(){
  $$(".photoLink").mouseenter(function(){
    $$(this).find(".img_menu").css("margin-top","-20px");
  });

  $$("#photoLink").mouseleave(function(){
    $$(this).find(".img_menu").css("margin-top","0px");
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because ID of ane element mus be unique, use class instead

```
<ul id="products" style="list-style:none;">
    $for item in data.response["Galleries"]:
     <li style="float:left" class="photoLink">
      <a href="$item['PhotoUrl']">
        <img src=$item["PhotoUrl"] alt="加载失败" style="max-width:75px;max-height:75px" title="点击查看大图"/>
         </a>
        <div class="img_menu" style="height:20px;width:75px;background-color:black;opacity:0.5"/>
     </li>
</ul>
```

then you need to target the `img_menu` element which is inside the current `li`

```
$$(function ($) {
    $(".photoLink").hover(function () {
        $(this).find(".img_menu").css("margin-top", "-20px");
    }, function () {
        $(this).find(".img_menu").css("margin-top", "0px");
    });
});
```